# JQuery add attribute function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('#section_option').change(function () {
      var selectedClass = $("#section_option option:selected").val();
      if (selectedClass != 0) {
        //alert("You have selected the class - " + selectedClass);
        $("#sectionname").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#sectionname").removeClass("disabled");
      } else if(selectedClass == 0) {
        alert("0 selected");
        $("#sectionname").addAttr("disabled");
        $("#sectionname").addClass("disabled");
      }     
    });
```

First portion of code i.e removing of attr and class is working fine but when i am trying to lock the input again when user switches back to option val 0, it is not happening due to some reason.

Comment: `addAttr` doesn’t exist. Please read the [documentation](//api.jquery.com/attr/). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not addAttr("disabled") is attr("disabled",true);

```
$('#section_option').change(function () {
  var selectedClass = $("#section_option option:selected").val();
  if (selectedClass != 0) {
    //alert("You have selected the class - " + selectedClass);
    $("#sectionname").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#sectionname").removeClass("disabled");
  } else if(selectedClass == 0) {
    alert("0 selected");
    $("#sectionname").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#sectionname").addClass("disabled");
  }     
});
```

Or you can use prop:

```
$("#sectionname").prop("disabled",true);
```